# How to locate multiple text element within class in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

For on my test i need to verify highlighted text (Lexington, KY) using my protractor test.

```
<li id="address" class="list">
<div class="content">
<small class="mb-1">
<span>
Suite # 278
<br>
</span>
**Lexington, KY**
</small>
</li>
```

How to verify highlighted text using css OR cssContainingText locator?

Comment: Try:
`driver.findelement(by.xpath(".//span[contains(text, Suite # 278)]");`
`driver.findelement(by.xpath(".//li[contains(text, **Lexington, KY** )]");`
`driver.findelement(by.xpath(".//li[text(), Suite # 278)]");`
`driver.findelement(by.xpath(".//li[text(), Lexington, KY)]");`

Comment: @Kishan - thank you for your reply, but we are not using xpath. can you suggest for cssContainingText locator?

Answer (score 1):

Actually Protractor creators have put great [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) in place , and pls read it thoroughly to gain good knowledge on usage of `css` & `cssContainingText`. I will answer your question in short here - Use `element(by.cssContainingText('.content','Lexington'))`

UPDATE 1:
In case you want to add an assertion .. do this - `expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.content','Lexington'))).toContain('Lexington, KY')`

Comment: tried but i am getting message ,Expected 'Suite # 271
    Lexington, KY' to equal 'Lexington, KY'.

Comment: I gave the `div` css , so it will get the complete text ... Just use `toContain()`.. I have updated the answer

Comment: thank you aditya, i have dynamic value. but i have parameterized and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For one I am confused because it seems like you are never closing the content div...is it closed after the li is closed?

Anyway...I would simply change the HTML so that you don't need some crazy convoluted mess of a selector. I would do it like this:

```
<li id="address" class="list">
  <div class="content">
    <small class="mb-1">
      <span>
        Suite # 278
        <br>
      </span>
      <cityState>Lexington, KY</cityState>
    </small>
</li>

function checkCityState(){
  return element(by.tagName('cityState')).getText();
}

expect(checkCityState()).toBe('Lexington, KY');
```

Comment: If you can't or do not want to add that tag I think that "return element(by.id('address')).element(by.css('.mb-1>span::after')).getText();" may also work (as the convoluted way, heh).